# Unable to get dotLess to work

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3, dotless

I am using [dotLess](http://www.dotlesscss.org/).

I followed all their instructions (which seems simple enough) it's only 4 steps :)

my minimal web.config looks like this:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
     <section name="dotless" type="dotless.Core.configuration.DotlessConfigurationSectionHandler,dotless.Core" />
  </configSections>
  <dotless minifyCss="false" cache="true" />
<system.web>
      <httpHandlers>
        <add type="dotless.Core.LessCssHttpHandler, dotless.Core" validate="false" path="*.LESS" verb="*" />
      </httpHandlers>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="LessHttpHandler" type="dotless.Core.LessCssHttpHandler, dotless.Core" preCondition="integratedMode" path="*.less" verb="*" />
        </handlers>
</system.webServer>
  </configuration>
```

I've added my .less files in my content folder (i am using ASP.NET MVC - Razor ViewEngine)

my layout has a link to my .less include file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/css" type="text/css" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.less")" />
```

I have also added the a reference in my web application to dotless.Core.dll

Yet despite all of the when i do a simple styling of the page's body backround to black, nothing happens, for some reason it aint kicking in.

Am i missing something here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you set the httphandler to run on requests? Add this:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"></modules>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

have you tried accessing the Site.less file directly with your browser? If there is a syntax error in your less it will be output there..

If you get a 404 on that page the web.config is the problem, but I can't find anything wrong with it at the moment.

Are you running in Cassini or are you running on IIS7?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this may be the cause, but in your link tag, rel value should be "stylesheet", not "stylesheet/css".

Also, I don't use ASP MVC but don't you need a tag around the Url.Content, like so?

```
<%= Url.Content("~/Content/Site.less") %>
```

Comment: Regarding the tagging: he is using the Razor view engine which has a little different syntax than the <% %> of the WebForms view engine.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried setting the `cache` to `false`? On some machines I've had issues with it.