# Could not load type 'dotless.Core.LessCssHttpHandler ' from assembly 'dotless.Core' when trying to access .less-file

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-6, dotless

I get the following error in an IIS6-site when I try to access a .less-file:

```
Detailed error information (authorized by permissions to functions)
Error occured   13.02.2013 10:30:19
User IP 93.89.112.52
User Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:18.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/18.0
Url http://www.oppdal.kommune.no/Templates/SSP.MasterPages/Static/css/style.less
Referer (none)
Exception details:
ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load type 'dotless.Core.LessCssHttpHandler ' from assembly 'dotless.Core'. (C:\prokom\Oppdal Kommune CMS6R2Newest2\web.config line 377)
Stack trace:

[ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load type 'dotless.Core.LessCssHttpHandler
    ' from assembly 'dotless.Core'. (C:\prokom\Oppdal Kommune CMS6R2Newest2\web.config line 377)]
   at System.Web.Configuration.ConfigUtil.GetType(String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement, XmlNode node, Boolean checkAptcaBit, Boolean ignoreCase)
   at System.Web.Configuration.HttpHandlerAction.Create()
   at System.Web.Configuration.HandlerFactoryCache..ctor(HttpHandlerAction mapping)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.GetFactory(HttpHandlerAction mapping)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.MapHttpHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath path, String pathTranslated, Boolean useAppConfig)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.MapHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

[Inner exception TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'dotless.Core.LessCssHttpHandler
    ' from assembly 'dotless.Core'.]
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName)
   at System.RuntimeType.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
   at System.Web.Configuration.ConfigUtil.GetType(String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement, XmlNode node, Boolean checkAptcaBit, Boolean ignoreCase)
```

Web.config in httpHandlers-section:

```
<add type="
    dotless.Core.LessCssHttpHandler
    ,dotless.Core" validate="false"
    path="*.LESS" verb="*" />
```

dotless.Core of version 1.3.1.0 is in the bin-folder.

What is the cause of this and how do I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I had put mine in the wrong httpHandlers section.  It goes in the system.web section instead of system.webServer.

I also found this:
[Unable to get dotLess to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7282222/unable-to-get-dotless-to-work)

It didn't work for me, but it gave me the hint that I'd put it in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

on the last version is  diffrent:

```
<add name="dotless" path="*.less" verb="GET" type="dotless.Core.LessCssHttpHandler,dotless.AspNet" resourceType="File" preCondition="" />
```

Comment: Haven't logged into SO in ages but had to now to upvote this answer that just saved me a lot of pain - thanks!